# Can't open pdf using itextsharp

Tags: itext

I'm using itextsharp version 5. I'm having a issue with some pdfs that cannot be opened using PdfReader. I'm able to read it with adobe viewer. Does anyone know the reason I'm getting this exception

{"Rebuild failed: trailer not found.; Original message: Invalid object number. at file pointer 2999592"}

```
           try
        {

            var reader = new PdfReader("1250_corrupted.pdf");

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Exception -->{0}", e);
        }
```

Comment: You have a reference to an object number at byte 2999592 in the document, and that object number is invalid. For instance: I once saw a PDF that had an object with object number `-1`. My first reaction was: that's not possible? My second reaction was: but it opens in Adobe Reader! My third reaction was: that shouldn't work. And if your problem is similar to the problem I just described, that should also be your reaction: it shouldn't work. Adobe Reader fixed a problem that shouldn't have been there. Save the file with Adobe Reader and it will be fixed. Use that saved file. That should work.

Comment: If the file already is called `*_corrupted.pdf`, the reason might be that the file is *corrupted*...